# Basic algebraic equation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok thats very basic but dont get it , I have the following equation  $R-A X-B \dfrac{A X}{2 B}=0$ 
the right result of it is  $R- \dfrac{3 A X}{2}=0$

well, now when I attempt to solve it I do the following:  $A X+\dfrac{A X}{B}=R$, so what I have done here is cancel the $B$ that is multiplying with one of the $B$'s which are dividing, I don't see why that is wrong, but I guess that's where I make the mistake.. Can anyone tell me why please? Cheeers!

Comment: "one of the B's"?  There's more than one B dividing?

Comment: yeah well is divided by 2*B , so B*B, 2 B's. cheers

Comment: 2*B is *not* the same as B*B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2*B is not B squared, it is just 2 times B.  So you have one B in the numerator and one in the denominator, and they cancel completely.  There is no B left in the denominator after the cancellation.  But there is a "2".

Comment: goooosh...embarrassed... :$ ! thaanks

Comment: I have done things equally embarrassing more times than I can count.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
$$
R - A X - B \cdot \frac{A X}{2 B} = R - A X - \frac{A B X}{2 B}
                                  = R - A X - \frac{A X}{2}
                                  = R - A X \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \right)
                                  = R - \frac{3 A X}{2}
$$

Comment: how did you edit it so it looks that good?

Comment: Look at the help for formatting, in particular [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). You should be able to ask to edit your own post and look at how I wrote it.

Comment: ok sweet! Ill have a look at it

Comment: and one last thing please...at the end of the quation, where does the X go? -AX(3/2)= -3AX/2?

Comment: Stupid braino. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: ooh ok, thank god hahaha ;) cheers!

Comment: BTW, your final $X = \dfrac{2 R}{3 A}$.